# C++ can't derive template parameters for high-order functions

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-argument-deduction, type-deduction

When I use have template function which accepts another function as a parameter, C++ can't derive template parameters. It's very annoying to specify them all the time. How can I define the following function such that I don't have to specify type parameters every time?

```
#include <functional>

template <typename S, typename T>
T apply(const S& source, const function<T (const S&)>& f) {
  return f(source);
}

template <typename S, class Functor, typename T>
T applyFun(const S& source, const Functor& f) {
  return f(source);
}

int main() {
  // Can't derive T. Why?
  apply(1, [](int x) { return x + 1; });
  // Compiles
  apply<int, int>(1, [](const int& x) { return x + 1; });
  // Can't derive T. Kind of expected.
  applyFun(1, [](int x) { return x + 1; });
}
```

It makes sense to me why it can't derive type parameter in the second function, but not in the first one (since `x + 1` is `int`, so it should deduce that `T = int`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A template parameter must appear in a function parameter type to be deductible. Moreover lambdas are not functions so, whatsoever the return type of a lambda cannot participate to template argument deduction.

But in this case, there is no need to specify the return type. Return type deduction can do the job:

```
template <typename S, class Functor>
auto applyFun(const S& source, const Functor& f) {
  return f(source);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use C++17, you can use the deduction guides for `std::function` as follows

```
template <typename S, typename F,
          typename T = typename decltype( std::function{std::declval<F>()} )::result_type>
T applyFun (S const & source, F const & f)
 {  
   return f(source);
 }
```

but, as pointed by Oliv, for your example function there is non need of `T` because you can use `auto` (from C++14; `auto ... -> decltype(f(source))` in C++11).

**-- EDIT --**

The OP say

> The good thing about this solution is that I can use T inside the function (e.g. if I want to implement vector_map).

You can detect and use `T`, also inside the function, using a `using`

Something as

```
template <typename S, typename F>
auto applyFun (S const & source, F const & f)
 {  
   using T = typename decltype( std::function{f} )::result_type;

   return f(source);
 }
```

or simpler: `using T = decltype( f(source) );`.

---

The OP also observe that

> The downside is that for some reason now I can't write `[] (const auto& x) { ... }` in function call.

Correct.
Because `std::function` template types can't be deduced from a generic-lambda.

But using the fact that you know the type of the argument, you can use `decltype()` again

```
template <typename S, typename F,
          typename T = decltype(std::declval<F const>()(std::declval<S const>()))>
T applyFun (S const & source, F const & f)
 { return f(source); }
```

This solution should works also for C++14 and C++11.

Comment: The good thing about this solution is that I can use `T` inside the function (e.g. if I want to implement `vector_map`). The downside is that for some reason now I can't write `[] (const auto& x) { ... }` in function call.

Comment: @dyukha - answer improved: hope this helps